# Print each word on separate line

Tags: c, assembly, x86-16

I'm unable to understand a few lines in the code I'm going to provide below.

```
int sc=-1;
while (strings[sc++]!=0)
{
_asm{
PUSH SI;
MOV SI,sc; get pointer
MOV DL,strings[SI]; get character 
CMP DL,' '; if not space
JNE next
MOV AH,2H; display new line 
MOV DL,10H; what is significance of this line? 
INT 21H; And this one 
MOV DL,13H ; what is significane of this line 
next: MOV AH,2H; display character
INT 21H;
POP SI;
}
}
```

there are a couple of lines I have written in their comments whose significance I am unaware of. Also I m very new to assembly language programming and this is something i read in a text book

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with this code: It uses the wrong ASCII codes (13H and 10H instead of 13 and 10), and it increments `sc` before using it. I suggest getting a better book because the author obviously did not test their code.

Comment: actually sc was initialized with -1 thats not a problem its my fault i provided partial code but 10H and 13H was wrong in the textboox thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> MOV DL,10H; what is significance of this line?
> ```

The `10H` is most probably a typo that should have read `10` which is the ASCII code for a linefeed. It moves the cursor 1 row down on the screen.

> ```
> MOV DL,13H ; what is significane of this line
> ```

The `13H` is most probably a typo that should have read `13` which is the ASCII code for a carriage return. It moves the cursor to the far left on the screen.

> ```
> INT 21H; And this one
> ```

The `INT 21H` instruction is a DOS system call that performs the function for whom you've put the function number in the `AH` register.

---

The whole code will output the current character if it is not a space character.
If it is a space character, then the code performs a newline sequence (carriage return + linefeed).

Because of the post-increment `sc++` that happened before this inline assembly code, the code will only work fine if the `MOV DL,strings[SI]` instruction is replaced with `MOV DL,strings[SI-1]`.

---

Thanks to [interjay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516484/print-each-word-on-seperate-line/47516865#comment81989830_47516865) for catching the typos.

Comment: The ASCII codes are actually wrong. They should be 10 and 13 decimal, not 10 and 13 hexadecimal (which is what the H suffix represents).

Comment: @interjay Nice catch. I've edited the answer with credits.

Comment: Because of the post-increment `sc++` that happened before this inline assembly code, the code will only work fine if the `MOV DL,strings[SI]` instruction is changed into `MOV DL,strings[SI-1]`.